# Updated some software - now cinnamon won't work, I think Gnome Desktop became default from unity, how to change this?

Tags: 12.10, unity, gnome, cinnamon

I updated my ubuntu 12.10 today and everything has got changed. The color, theme, the top window bar looks different.

Earlier I was using Unity and it looks now Gnome has become the default. I was also using cinnamon so I am not sure if it is still working or that too got broke. How to get to default settings ? (I think I was using Unity + Cinnamon) ?

This is what I get in terminal, it looks all the desktop environments are running!

```
xxx@xxx:~$ ps -A | egrep -i "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon"

   22 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
 2172 ?        00:00:02 gnome-keyring-d
 2183 ?        00:00:00 cinnamon-sessio
 2266 ?        00:00:01 cinnamon-settin
 2304 ?        00:05:23 cinnamon
 2349 ?        00:00:00 polkit-gnome-au
 2358 ?        00:00:00 cinnamon-fallba
 2506 ?        00:00:00 cinnamon-screen
 5631 ?        00:00:02 gnome-system-mo
 5697 ?        00:00:00 gnome-terminal
 5703 ?        00:00:00 gnome-pty-helpe

xxx@xxx:~$ ls /usr/bin/*session

/usr/bin/cinnamon-session  /usr/bin/ck-launch-session  /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an answer! First remove cinamon completely by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove cinnamon
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove .*cinnamon.*
sudo apt-get remove .*nemo.*
```

and then install it again by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

After installing all the necessary packages, just log out and change the log-in option to Cinnamon. Enjoy Cinnamon 2.0.6 stable , well don’t try it if you have upgraded to 13.10 instead of updating because it has many issues with 13.10 .It seems that the problems with Unity haven't been fixed and some users might have problems logging into their system.